# How to set the minimum Java version in Android Studio 0.8.1

Tags: android-studio

How to set the minimum Java version in my project in Android Studio 0.8.1? Earlier I used Android Studio 0.6.1 and could do this in "Project Settings". But now I couldn't find this option. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> How to set the minimum Java version in my project in Android Studio 0.8.1?

You do so in the build.gradle file in the app module

Answer (score 0):

FIle-> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Compiler (Expand it by clicking left arrow) -> Java Compiler -> You can change the Project bytecode version here

[image]